# How to fix Twilio URL shortener that is not redirecting?

Tags: sms, url-shortener

I set up our messaging service to allow for link shortening within Twilio. I am particularly interested in link tracking capabilities and webhooks.

Added the website domain, verified it. Put in the DNS TXT records according to their instructions. Everything seems to be in order. Yet when I send a link with the ShortenURL=True the link sends as a shortened link but when clicked it doesn't redirect so it takes the user to a 404 page.

I am wondering if there is an issue with the DNS records... or if I am supposed to configure a special domain exclusively for our own shortened links.

the shortened link:
https://portraitsbychristopher.com/qMqpqUP9Wg

Where it should redirect:
https://portraitsbychristopher.com/Tiaras

Tried reading the Twilio docs.

Answer (score 0):

Did u add the DNS records that point the A to 3 IPs